# Arrays and if Statements: Array object not passable into if statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

Please consider the following code:

```
public JButton math_button[] = new JButton[5];
    for (int h = 0; h <math_button.length; h++) {
        if(event.getSource()==math_button[h]) {
            String button_press = math_button[h].getText();     
            if(math_button[h].getText().equals("Equals")) {
                secondn = Integer.parseInt(math_input.getText());
                System.out.println(firstn + " math operator " + secondn + " and "+ math_button[h].getText());
                System.out.println(calc.Math(button_press, firstn, secondn));
            } else {
                firstn = Integer.parseInt(math_input.getText());
                //math_input.setText("");
                //placeholder = calc.Math(math_button[h].getText(), firstn, secondn);
                //int secondn = Integer.parseInt(math_input.getText());
                //int result = calc.Math(math_button[h].getText(), firstn, secondn);
                //math_input.setText(Integer.toString(firstn));
                //math_input.setText(Integer.toString(placeholder));
            }
        }
    }
```

What is the reason that despite the variable `button_press` being set to the name of an array object outside of the second IF (nested) loop, the test condition variable `math_button[h].getText()`is always passed to the `calc.Math` method?

Is the variable of the `button_press` string being overridden by the nested IF statement?

Comment: Use `String#equals` to compare Strings. `==` compares object references

Comment: Luiggi, I see you point about the possible duplication but I never would have found, or even thought of, asking about string comparisons.

Comment: @obious - The reason it's a dupe here is that the (ever popular) SO question about comparing a `String` in Java is the actual problem / error, and any answer to this question will simply be the same answer.

Comment: Noooooooooooo !!!!!! =''''(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String#equals()` as

```
if(math_button[h].getText().equals("Equal")) {
```

Equals `==` operator only compares the references with each other; not the actual text content.

***EDIT** :*

The reason `equals()` didn't work is because the button name is `Equals` (notice the `s`)

```
public String[] name = {"Add", "Mulitply", "Divide", "Subtract", "Equals"};
```

Hence, your `if` condition should actually be

```
if(math_button[h].getText().equals("Equals")) {
```

Comment: While your answer is correct, the problem and solution are stated in the possible dup question.

Comment: Thanks but I've tried your suggestion and it hasn't worked.

Comment: @obious Check update. You are missing an `s`.

Comment: I noticed that, and changed it accordingly but it still doesn't work

Comment: @obious Can you add a `println()` just before the `if` and check the actual string?

Comment: Just done that, 'Equals', without the quotations obviously, is returned. It's interesting, if I put an 'Equals' IF statement into the calc.Math method, the code within that segment is returned. For whatever reason, only the 'Equals'variable is being passed

Comment: It should work then. Can you update your question with the current changes in your code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34332/discussion-between-obious-and-ravi-thapliyal)